# Multiple Search core result web parts with different scopes at one page

Tags: 2007, search-results, search-scope

I want to display 4 Search core result web parts with different scopes on one search result page. This is the scenario:

1. User searches for term "test" entering the keywords into Search box.
2. User is redirected to the result page where are 4 Search core result web parts.
3. Each result web part has different scope.
4. Result web parts should be filtered by keyword specified by user and by the scope specified in web part settings.

So far I have find out, I have to use different *Cross-Web Part query ID* for each web part. This way I am able to set the scope in *Fixed Keyword Query*, eg. scope:"MyScope". But the keywords entered by user are ignored. All the items in the scope are displeyed.

My question is, how can I pass the query string parameter "k" (entered by user into Search Box) into my Search core result web parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I have found the workaround. Use **Federated results** web part instead.

There is an option for **"Append to query"** just like in SP 2010. Only issue is with paging. Hope I will find a solution OOTB.